# What if in potentiometer, the loops are not balanced to cancel the potential and current flows?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance

[image]

As described in the book (image) that loops should be balanced with equal potential with help of the galvanometer. What if the we do not balance it to zero and have some current flowing? Can we still do the calculations and how? If not then why?